# Django "and" Pinax or just Pinax?

Tags: django, pinax

I'm developing a personal project. The project is "finished", but now I want to add a social app. I think pinax is ready for this task. I would like to know something:

Can I use pinax in my project like a django app? Or do I need to rework my project using pinax?

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are two ways to approach what you're trying to do. As celopes said, since Pinax is made up of a bunch of reusable Django apps you can just pick and choose the ones you want and add those to your project.

The other approach would be to start from one of the [Pinax template projects](http://github.com/pinax/pinax/tree/master/pinax/projects/) and integrate your code and customizations.

Either way, you don't need to rewrite your code, although it will probably take some work to integrate the pieces nicely.

Comment: Thanks guy's, i love the Django way with the plug app... thanks again :)

Answer (score 4):

From the [Pinax](http://pinaxproject.com/) website:

> By integrating numerous reusable Django apps to take care of the things that many sites have in common, it lets you focus on what makes your site different.

So Pinax is composed of reusable django apps. Use the ones you need.

[Documentation is here](http://pinaxproject.com/docs/).