# Django Pinax - How to use apps in other projects, not cloned Pinax projects?

Tags: python, django, pinax

This is a similar question,

[Django "and" Pinax or just Pinax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1977004/django-and-pinax-or-just-pinax)

and one of the answers specifies a link to documentation, but that documentation doesn't describe how to plug a Pinax app into a separate project. Or I just can't find it there. Are there any other sources that have the easy way of achieving this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pinax, *is* a collection of reusable django apps packaged together with templates and some "project code."

If you want just a particular feature of pinax like mailer, wiki, notification, photos, you are better of using the original projects that pinax included.

If you are going to tie up all these into some project [like the ones that can be generated by a command](http://pinaxproject.com/blog/2010/12/31/types-pinax-starter-projects/), you may use the generated project as the base project and add your stuff into it.

Using just the one app that [pinax itself uses](https://github.com/pinax/pinax/blob/master/requirements/pinax.txt) for the specific function you are interested in, would be my preferred way, not the least because many of these packages themselves have better alternatives, mostly as newer versions.

```
--extra-index-url=http://dist.pinaxproject.com/dev/

docutils==0.6
gdata==1.3.3
Pygments==1.3.1
python-openid==2.2.5
python-twitter==0.6
pytz==2010h
simplejson==2.0.9
textile==2.1.4
vobject==0.8.1c
Markdown==2.0.3
ybrowserauth==1.2
geopy==0.94
diff-match-patch==20090804
django-atomformat==0.1.1.dev1
creole==1.1

# vobject depends on dateutil. it requires >=1.1. OS X ships with 1.2 with
# Python 2.5 and requiring anything newer will break for --development. this
# is not an issue for the released tarball
python-dateutil>=1.1

Django==1.2.5
django-ajax-validation==0.1.3
django-announcements==0.1.2
django-avatar==1.0.4
django-dbtemplates==0.5.8
django-notification==0.2a1.dev4
django-pagination==1.0.7
django-robots==0.6.1
django-messages==0.4.2
django-threadedcomments==0.5.2
django-extensions==0.4.1
django-uni-form==0.7.0
django-bookmarks==0.1.0
django-gravatar==0.1.0
django-mailer==0.2a1.dev3
django-friends==0.1.5
django-locations==0.1.1
django-oembed==0.1.1
django-swaps==0.5.3
django-flag==0.2.dev9
django-db-log==1.0.1
django-attachments==0.3.1
django-markup==0.3
django-microblogging==0.2.dev1
django-wakawaka==0.4.dev5
sorl-thumbnail==3.2.5
django-generic-flatblocks==0.9.1
django-frontendadmin==0.4
django-filter==0.5.3
django-photologue==2.3
django-tagging==0.3.1
django-staticfiles==0.2
django-debug-toolbar==0.8.3
django-tagging-ext==0.2.0
django-voting==0.1
django-sorting>=0.1
django-groups==0.1.dev10
biblion==0.1.dev6
django-email-confirmation==0.2.dev4
django-openid==0.2.3.dev1
django-timezones==0.2.dev1
idios==0.1.dev6
```